# My <span> tags are not working. elements are stacked instead of spanned out

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, vuejs2

Im following a tutorial from a website called @coursetro (AdobeXD, Vue, React, Angular) and I'm trying to build my header component up and when I run the program, all my header elements I had spanned out within my header components just come out stacked on top of each other. I've attached my HTML code along with the sass and js im using in vue.js. I know its something simple but I've been 2 days trying to figure this out. (I'm using: Balma, Sass)

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<div class="nav has-shadow">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-left">
      <a class="nav-item"><img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="Bulma logo" 
    width="354" height="101"></a>
    </div>

    <span class="nav-toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </span>

    <div class="nav-right nav-menu">

      <router-link to="/" class="nav-item r-item">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/faq" class="nav-item r-item">Features</router-link>
      <router-link to="/faq" class="nav-item r-item">About</router-link>
      <router-link to="/faq" class="nav-item r-item">FAQ</router-link>

      <div class="nav-item">
        <p class="control">
          <a class="button is-primary is-outlined">
            <span class="icon">
              <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
            </span>
            <span>Join Now</span>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'App'
}
</script>
<style lang="sass">
@import '../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass'
@import 'mq'

</style>
```

Best Regards

Comment: `<span>` doesn't mean 'spanned out' - it's an inline element to contain or group other elements (main use I see are for icons and text) - see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span.

Comment: A good way to investigate this is to eliminate all the other tech and get a confirmed structure working with just HTML and plain CSS. In this way you'll learn the fundamentals and you also get clean code to post as a snippet here so we can all help you. Right now we can't see what CSS is being applied to the <span>'s or any other elements. In any case, if you refer to an external tutorial, it would be nice if you can link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think misunderstood `<span>` . It is an inline element, as ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs already explained

You can achieve what you are trying to do with vue.js pretty easily:

```
<span v-on:click="toggle= !toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    <div v-show="toggle"class="nav-container">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
     </div>
</span>
```

The `v-show` makes it depending on the value of the `toggle` variable wether the div is displayed or not.
The `v-on:click="toggle= !toggle"` toggles the `toggle` variable when you click on the span. You can place the span somewhere else as well.